# How to animate text display to create a typewriting-esque effect in c#

Tags: c#, text, timer

I came up with a way to do this but it makes use of a timer. I searched a while online for alternate approaches but they all make use of timers too, but I do not want to use a timer.

Is there anyway this text animation effect can be achieved without the use of a timer?

Comment: And what's the purpose of not using timers? You can end up creating something-like-a-timer-but-not-an-explicit-timer solution, but if you need to write text in time intervals, how do you want to render the text overtime? Maybe you can ask Stephen Hawking and check if using another dimension will let you do so.......... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to use a Timer? It sounds ideal for this situation.

If there is a *very compelling reason* for not wanting to use a timer, you might be able to adapt the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to do what you need but it's unclear without seeing your code.

A somewhat hilarious alternative, would be to inherit from `Timer` and create your own type:

```
public class NotATimer : Timer
{
    public NotATimer()
    { }
 }
```

Comment: Finally decided to go with the timer.

Comment: @NiiLaryea - A wise choice